# Scale right column in grid to 100% of left column

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using foundations grid. I've got a grid with two columns and would like to have the content of the right column scale to 100% the height of the left column.

I made a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pesilasomu/3/edit?html,output) to illustrate my problem (you have to open the output in a seperate tab for some reasons).

That is how it looks:

[image]

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.0.3/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="width:50%">
  <div class="small-8 columns">
    <div class="row">
    left column first row
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    left column second row
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    left column third row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column fourth row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column fifth row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column sixth row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column seventh row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column eigth row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column ninth row
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
      <div class="row">
    this is supposed to scale to 100% of the size of the left column
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jugezujeme/1/)**

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;       
}
#row_box{
  display:table;
}
.child{
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:red;
}    
.child:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="width:50%">
  <div id="row_box"> // added id row_box
   
  <div class="large-8  child"> // added class child & removed columns
    <div class="row">
    left column first row
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    left column second row
    </div>
        <div class="row">
    left column third row
    </div>
            <div class="row">
    left column fourth row
    </div>
     </div>
    
    <div class="large-4 child">  // added class child & removed columns
      <div class="row">
    this is supposed to scale to 100% of the size of the left column
      </div>
       
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Note:
This -ve margin is coming from your css file.